# Setup Windows Authentication in ASP .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

Here's what I want to do (which I've done before but I'm clearly doing something that is not obvious to me...):

- ASP .NET 3.5 Intranet Application
- Want to have Windows Authentication against AD setup on the website
- When the user requests the page, fetch the user's username with the following code:

  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

I have IIS 7.5 and have setup the web application, disabled anonymous access and enabled Windows Authentication.

When the page is requested, the prompt for username / password is entered.

I entered the details but the prompt keeps coming up and eventually comes back with 401.

What on earth have I missed?

Comment: Just one more thing, I have this in my web.conig: <authentication mode="Windows" />

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a broblem with the Authorization (dond confuse with Authentication they completely diffrent), becuse the Authentication has been passed successfully after you've written the right user name and password, please try to set the appropriate privilegs to the user you try to login with, then try again. You can do that by set ting the right roles in the Authorization tab in the Security/Application tool of ASP.NET or by defining it manually by creating the right class... You'd better also chack the IIS policy if you deal with production code on IIS. If this is not working please post the Authentication code you've written.

Comment: Thats the thing, I havent written any authentication code at all. I thought that I would be granted access to the pages by adding the code below in the web.config and setting Windows Authentication to be true....I've simply added the following in web.config   <authentication mode="Windows" />
  '<authorization> 
   <deny users="?" /> 
  </authorization> 
  <identity impersonate="true" />'

Comment: See my answer below which is correct and reflects what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong. Was nothing to do with Authorization at all but I stupidly had written code a few days back throwing a 401 error when a certain condition was not met. Removing that proved that the setup done worked perfectly :)